# We need rename file like "report assinement 09.09.2020.xlsx" (with changing date line 08.09.2020 and so no) everyday to myproject.xlsx

Tags: powershell

**how do we remake the program for situation that
if we already have file myprojects.xlsx how do we rename latest file and delete old version? **

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'report assinement [0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[12][09][0-9][0-9].xlsx' |
    Sort @{Expression = {[datetime]::ParseExact(($_.BaseName -replace '.*(?=\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})'),'MM.dd.yyyy',$null)}; Descending = $true} |
        Select -First 1 |
            Rename-Item -NewName { 'myprojects.xlsx' } -WhatIf
```

Comment: If you're tring to replace `report assinement 09.09.2020` with `myproject`, why are you using `^remnants auto*`?

Comment: What is the goal? Is it to rename a file that contains `report assinement` and a date in the filename to `myproject.xlsx`? If so, will the date always be today's date?

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a file name `report assinement 09.09.2020.xlsx` where the date in the name always matches today's date, and you want to rename it to `myprojects.xlsx`, you can do the following:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format 'MM.dd.yyyy'
Get-ChildItem -Path "report assinement $date.xlsx" |
    Rename-Item -NewName { 'myprojects.xlsx' } -WhatIf
```

If you want to rename a file `report assinement 09.09.2020.xlsx` where the date can be any date to `myprojects.xlsx`, you can do the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'report assinement [0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[12][09][0-9][0-9].xlsx' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { 'myprojects.xlsx' } -WhatIf
```

If you only want to rename the date part of the file name, i.e. `report assinement 09.09.2020.xlsx` becomes `report assinement myprojects.xlsx`, you can do the following:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format 'MM.dd.yyyy'
Get-ChildItem -Path "report assinement $date.xlsx" |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace [regex]::Escape($date),'myprojects'} -WhatIf
```

If you are looking to rename the file `report assinement <date>.xlsx` where `<date>` is the latest date of all the files in a directory that contains many files named similarly, you can do the following. This handles filename collisions also.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'report assinement [0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[12][09][0-9][0-9].xlsx' |
    Sort @{Expression = {[datetime]::ParseExact(($_.BaseName -replace '.*(?=\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})'),'MM.dd.yyyy',$null)}; Descending = $true} |
        Select -First 1 |
            Rename-Item -NewName {
                if (Test-Path "$($_.Directory)\myprojects.xlsx") {
                    Remove-Item "$($_.Directory)\myprojects.xlsx"
                }
                'myprojects.xlsx'
            } -WhatIf
```

Be sure to remove `-WhatIf` if you are happy with the intended change. Keep in mind that in scenarios where multiple files could match the search criteria, there may be collisions during the rename step since you can't have two files with the same name in the same directory.

Comment: I added a scenario where you could have multiple files with multiple dates. It picks the file with the latest date and renames that one.

Comment: thank you but if we run the last code and we have already file myprojects.xlsx the program return error  E: \ Prices \ AutoPremium> powershell.exe -noexit. \ 1.ps1
Rename-Item: Unable to create file because it already exists.
E: \ Prices \ AutoPremium \ 1.ps1: 4 character: 13
+ Rename-Item -NewName {'myprojects.xlsx'}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: WriteError: (E: \ Prices \ AutoP ... 09.09.2020.xlsx: S
    tring) [Rename-Item], IOException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: RenameItemIOError, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.
    RenameItemCommand

Comment: What would you name the file if there are duplicates?

Comment: 'MM.dd.yyyy',$null)}; Descending = $true}   how do we remake this code with dd.MM.yyyy ?

Comment: Just change it to `'dd.MM.yyyy'`.

Comment: if we already have file myprojects.xlsx how do we rename latest file and delete old version?

Comment: I updated the last example to handle file name collisions.